# Google Photos search to show only local photos

Tags: google-photos

On my Android phone in Google Photos, I want to select and perform an operation only on photos which are actually stored on the device.  I tried a couple of search terms such as "local" and "local:" but I am really shooting in the dark here.  Is there a way I can filter or search and only show images which are on the phone, so I can then do normal operations on all of them at once?

There are several pre-defined searches available like "Videos" but I don't see any which do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

> perform an operation only on photos which are actually stored on the device.

If this "operation" is outside of the "Google Photos app" you can install an other gallery app that can search local photos, has "multi-selection" and "send"

Example:

- find local photos with alternative-gallery app
- select the photos
- send selected photos to ["scrambled-exif-app"](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.jarsilio.android.scrambledeggsif/) (= remove exif data from seleted photos and re-send)
- send result via email

[A Photo Manager](https://github.com/k3b/aphotomanager/wiki) (where i am the author of) is a gallery app with powerfull search functionality.

I am shure that other gallery apps can do this, too

Comment: Actually, the reason I want to do this is that I want to rename the images.  I can do this outside the app, but then in order to sync the changes to Google Drive I have to delete the photos and then re-upload them.  If I rename all the images locally in a single batch, I want to then select all the images renamed (either before or after the rename) and then "delete" them after I rename so Photos will think the renamed photos are new and re-upload them.

Comment: And yes, the fact that Google provides no native way to simply rename images is idiotic.